# XCode 4 can I copy the download from one machine to another

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store

Hi
I downloaded the XCode 4 which uses the app store to download and install and took over 8 hours for the 4.1 GB download to complete.

Can I copy this install from to another machine without having to do that massive download again?

Just to be clear I know how to move files between machines its more the location and what needs to be moved that I am interested in,

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How I got here is that I wanted to install MacPorts on a new MacBook Air, but I didn't have a CD drive for it so I thought I would just download it. I didn't realise that there is a small USB drive that comes with the MacBook Air from where I could have just install the slightly older but perfectly good for my purpose XCode.  Well you live and learn..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it’s worth, if you’re a registered developer you can download a single .dmg file from Apple’s website and install Xcode from that. The disc image can then be obviously copied wherever you wish.

Comment: The dmg would have been a better option but I didn't feel like paying the $99 to join just to be able to be able to install mac ports. If I did any mac development I would join.

Comment: The correct answer is posted below, but not flagged as such: If you have downloaded XCode from the AppStore, you can copy `/Applications/Install XCode.app` from one machine to another.

Comment: @ShawnVader you can join as a developer for free. What costs $99 is the one year developer license and not the account.

Answer (score 8):

I simply copied "/Applications/Install Xcode.app" from one machine to the other after the first machine downloaded from the App Store ($4.99 version). It worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, I never saw the Install Xcode, I think I was just looking for XCode

Answer (score 2):

I am stumped by other answers here - I have just downloaded XCode 4.3.2 for Lion (AFAIK latest at the moment) from this site:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

You only need a valid AppleID (**free of charge**) developer account. No credit card whatsoever.

The filtering & pagination on download page do not work properly / are somewhat weird, at least in FF. But you can still find and download the 1.8GB .dmg file there and install it wherever you want.

OP has stated that he has downloaded a 4.1GB file, so the versions might be different. I do not miss anything from mine though, it works (well, mostly - but that's just the quality of Apple software... :) ).

Comment: As of 1/4/2017, 8.2 and even the prerelease for 8.2.1 is now available on the URL listed here above in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just a *dmg file? That's what I have done one with a previous version. Just copied it and a normal install did the trick..

The newest is called xcode_4_and_ios_sdk_4.3__final and is in my download folder...

Comment: I was just writing the same and then I realized he’s bought Xcode through the Mac App Store, so there’s probably no single .dmg involved.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it was a mistake to purchase through the AppStore but it was just £2.99 and I didn't feel like paying the $99 to join just to be able to be able to install mac ports